# Is there a term for reduplication used to disambiguate categorization?

Tags: terminology, obscure-terms, reduplication

> Reduplication - noun - A word formed by or containing a reduplicated element. An act or instance of reduplicating as a grammatical pattern. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reduplication

Is there a term for the kind of reduplication where the two words are exactly the same but the first one narrows a category that could otherwise be interpreted more broadly?

e.g.

- Do you mean ***Indian Indian*** or American Indian?
- It is common both in Irish English and ***English English***.
- Do you mean cable television?  No, I mean ***television television***.

To be clear, I'm not looking for a term to describe reduplication for the purpose of intensification, as in: *"They have been together for a couple of weeks now".  "You mean "together together"?*  That kind of reduplication has [already been covered](//english.stackexchange.com/questions/119134/what-is-the-term-for-the-double-consecutive-use-of-a-word-with-stress-on-one-of).

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[What is the term for the double consecutive use of a word with stress on one of the words to alter its severity?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119134)*; of related interest: *[How did the phenomenon of doubling words come about?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43431)*, *[“Are you sure sure” — is this repetition grammatically correct?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50060)*.

Comment: I strongly urge user463240 to check out the first link in choster's comment above. It has two very good answers to the specific question being asked. Also, Lynn might consider moving the pleonasm answer to that question—although it seems to me that the replication of the words in the OP's examples here are not superfluous.

Comment: @SvenYargs and choster.  I always look for possible duplicates but I seem to be doing the wrong way.  When I post the title of the question, there is a dropdown list and that's where I check.  I'm amazed at how quickly you came up with possible duplicates when I didn't find any.  How do you do it?  Anyways, I tried to delete the question but I cannot, now that there's na answer.

Comment: @choster  I always look for possible duplicates but I seem to be doing the wrong way. When I post the title of the question, there is a dropdown list and that's where I check. I'm amazed at how quickly you came up with possible duplicates when I didn't find any. How do you do it? Anyways, I tried to delete the question but I cannot, now that there's na answer.

Comment: @user463240: No harm, no foul. I think your question is good (hence my upvote) and it appears that you could have searched on the key term _reduplication_ and not found the previous question. I don't know how choster did find it, but sometimes it's simply a matter of remembering the earlier one from the time when it first appeared; the other possibility is to search on likely alternative terms for (in this case) _reduplication_, such as _duplicate_, _duplication_, _double_, or _doubling_. Anyway, the search box to use is in the black bar at the top of the page.

Comment: @SvenYargs I've looked at the possible duplicate.  It's about "intensifiers" ("hungry-hungry" or just hungry?  "Together together, really?") My question is about two identical words where the first one differentiates the second. I think it may prove a good question to our data-bank.

Comment: I see the distinction you're making, but I still think that the answers "contrastive focus reduplication" and "antanaclasis" in response to the earlier question answer your question as well. I believe that the site is designed to retain duplicate questions so that if someone searches on the terms your question uses, they will come to this page even if the question is closed as a duplicate. I hope so, anyway, because I agree that keeping this question (with its redirect to the other question in place) would strengthen the overall database.

Comment: The poster's most recent edit now specifically asks what term (if any) describes contiguous word duplication in a way that differentiates it from the type of duplication discussed in the previous question. I don't know whether such a term exists, but I do think that this revision by the poster differentiates the current question from the earlier one, so I've retracted my vote to close.

Comment: Amusing as it is for this question to be marked "duplicate", I don't think this is a duplicate question.

Comment: The old question still answers the new question. This is still contrastive reduplication.

Comment: I can barely get my head round the edited title. It looks so jargony.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called `contrastive focus reduplication` in [a paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/B%3ANALA.0000015789.98638.f9) on the exact construction by Ghomeshi et al (2004). Natural Language & Linguistic Theory 22: 307–357, 2004.

EDIT
The paper is 52 pages long, the following are extracts taken from the first 8 pages.

> **CONTRASTIVE FOCUS REDUPLICATION IN ENGLISH
>
>   (THE SALAD-SALAD PAPER)**
>
> ABSTRACT. This paper presents a phenomenon of colloquial English that
>   we call Contrastive Reduplication (CR), involving the copying of words
>   and sometimes phrases as in It’s tuna salad, not SALAD-salad, or Do
>   you LIKE-HIM-like him? Drawing on a corpus of examples gathered from
>   natural speech, written texts, and television scripts, we show that CR
>   restricts the interpretation of the copied element to a ‘real’ or
>   prototypical reading. (...)

Examples of this construction are

> (1)a. I’ll make the tuna salad, and you make the SALAD–salad. ©
>   b. LIKE-’EM-like-’em? Or, I’d-like-to-get-store-credit-for-that amount
>   like-’em?2 ©
>   c. Is he French or FRENCH–French?
>   d. I’m up, I’m just not UP–up. ©
>   e. That’s not AUCKLAND–Auckland, is it? ©
>   f. My car isn’t MINE–mine; it’s my parents’.
>   g. Oh, we’re not LIVING-TOGETHER–living-together.

(...)

> The semantic effect of this construction is to focus the denotation of
>   the reduplicated element on a more sharply delimited, more specialized,
>   range. For instance, SALAD–salad in (1a) denotes specifically green salad
>   as opposed to salads in general, and, in the context in which (1e) was used,
>   AUCKLAND–Auckland denotes the city in New Zealand as opposed to
>   other cities that may happen to have this name.
>   (...)
>   The use of a word or phrase often leaves open some vagueness, lack of precision, or ambiguity. **CR is used as one way to clarify such situations, by specifying a prototypical denotation of the lexical item in contrast to a potentially looser or
>   more specialized reading.** This is clearest when CR is applied to simple
>   nouns: [(e.g.)]
>
> (3) c. She wasn’t a fancy cow, a Hereford or Black Angus or something,
>   just a COW–cow. ©

(...)

> This characterization is precisely the informal one given by Horn
>   (1993). He briefly discusses CR (which he labels, following Dray
>   (1987), the ‘double construction’) stating: “As a rough approximation,
>   we can say that **the reduplicated modifier singles out a member or
>   subset of the extension of the noun [or verb, or adjective, or
>   preposition – JG et al.] that represents a true, real, default, or
>   prototype instance**” (p. 48). As already seen in (1), CR can apply to
>   not only to nouns, but to a range of lexical categories. Regardless of
>   the lexical category, however, reduplication signals that the “real”
>   or prototypical meaning of the lexical item is intended:
>
> (4)a. Are you LEAVING–leaving? [i.e., are you “really” leaving (for
>   good), or are you just stepping out for a minute]
>   b. A: Are you nervous?
>   B: Yeah, but, you know, not NERVOUS–nervous. [i.e., not “really” nervous] ©
>   (...)
>   Lawrence Horn (p.c.), in more recent work on CR (which he now calls
>   ‘**lexical cloning**’), categorizes the semantics of this construction
>   into four types: **(a) prototype** meaning (which we have already
>   discussed), **(b) literal meaning, (c) intensified meaning**, and
>   **(d) ‘value-added’** meaning. An example of literal meaning appears in (12), where reduplication signals that a literal rather than
>   euphemistic interpretation of coming in for coffee is intended:
>
> (12) [Dialogue between a married couple, recently separated and
>   now living apart.]
>   A: Maybe you’d like to come in and have some coffee?
>   B: Yeah, I’d like that.
>   A: Just COFFEE-coffee, no double meanings. ©

Comment: It would be interesting if you could expand your answer.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I took the opportunity of editing your post and adding a few relevant extracts. Hope you don't mind. EDIT: I was unaware that this is a duplicate question.

Comment: I fear I may have breached copyright issues; however, the author and the title of the paper is clearly stated, so I'll leave it up to the mods to decide.

Comment: Nice selection, Mari-Lou—useful and judicious. if I were a judge in an intellectual property case, I would classify this as "fair use," not "theft." And if I were the author of the (much longer) article from which the excerpts came, I would look at this selection as positive publicity for my work.

Comment: @Mari-LouA thanks for enlarging my answer. your quotations are within DMCA exemptions on fair use.

Comment: Why would it be called **RE**duplication?  Reduplication is reduplication.  Duplication is duplication.

Comment: (Fantastic answer and editing BTW! :) )

Comment: @JoeBlow that's just what it's called. The term is used in Sapir's (1921) linguistics textbook *Language: An Introduction to the Study of Speech.* I'm guessing the term is in familiar use by 1921 since Sapir does not pause to explain it's derivation.

Comment: JL - I appreciate that; I'm just criticising that author's choice of term!  Cheers...

Comment: @JoeBlow I also wonder why REduplication?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Great editing. "Magna cun laude".

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the term you're looking for is *pleonasm*, though the specific examples you've cited may be a particular sub-category of pleonasm.

> Pleonasm is the use of more words or parts of words than is necessary for clear expression: examples are black darkness, or burning fire.

Source [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm).

They can also be generically termed as *intensifiers*.  All intensifiers are, to some extent, redundant, but they add clarity.  I don't know if there's a particular term for an intensifier that is specifically the same word used twice.